# Is there a better way to convert from UTCTime to EpochTime?

Tags: haskell, time, epoch

I want to set a file's modification time to the time I got from exif data.

To get the time from exif, I found :

```
Graphics.Exif.getTag :: Exif -> String -> IO (Maybe String)
```

To set the file modification time, I found :

```
System.Posix.Files.setFileTimes :: FilePath -> EpochTime -> EpochTime -> IO ()
```

Assuming I do find a Time in Exif, I need to convert a String to an EpochTime.

- With `parseTime` I can get a `UTCTime`.
- With `utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds` I can get a `POSIXTime`
- With a `POSIXTime` I can more or less get an `EpochTime`

To convert from a `UTCTime` to `EpochTime` this typechecks, but I'm not
sure it's correct :

```
fromIntegral . fromEnum . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds $ etime
```

This is part of a function getTime that will return the time from Exif
data, if present, otherwise the file's modification time :

```
getTime (path,stat) = do
 let ftime                 = modificationTime $ stat
     err (SomeException _) = return ftime
 time <- liftIO $ handle err $ do
   exif <- Exif.fromFile path
   let getExifTime = MaybeT . liftIO . Exif.getTag exif
   res <- runMaybeT $ do
     tmp <- msum . map getExifTime $ [ "DateTimeOriginal","DateTimeDigitized", "DateTime" ]
     MaybeT . return . parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S" $ tmp
   case res of
     Nothing    -> return ftime
     Just etime -> return . fromIntegral . fromEnum . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds $ etime
 return (path,time)
```

My question is

Is there a better/simpler way to convert the time ? ( maybe using different libaries )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Data.Time` is the best supported time library, so I would definitely agree with
your choice of using it to parse the string representation of date and time
that you get out of the Exif data.

Are you sure you need to *set* the modification time of a file? That's unusual. But if so, then yes, you'll need to use the `System.Posix` libraries on a Posix system.

If you only need to *read* the modification of a file,
you would be better off using the more generic function
`System.Directory.getModificationTime`. Unfortunately, that function
also uses a non-standard time library, `System.Time` from the
long-deprecated `old-time` package in this case.
So you would still need to do some similar machinations.

Your conversion from `POSIXTime` to `EpochTime` happens to be
OK in this particular case, but in general it's not ideal way to go.

The `EpochTime` type,
a.k.a the `time_t` type from C, does
not support any direct way to be constructed in Haskell without going via
an integral value, even though it itself is not necessarily integral
depending on your operating system.
You could go via C using the FFI if those potential fractions of a second are
important to you.
Here that's certainly not important, because
you're getting the seconds from an `%S` format parameter which can have no fractional part.
Anyway. you will still need to do some kind of rounding or truncating
to get from the non-integral `UTCTime` type to `EpochTime`.

You're currently just using the `Enum` instance of `POSIXTime` to do the
rounding/truncating
for you, however it decides to.
Again, in this particular case it doesn't really matter, because we happen
to know that the value will be integral.
But in general, it's better to specify it
yourself explicitly by using `floor`, `ceiling`, or `round`. E.g.,

```
return $ maybe ftime (fromInteger . round . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds) etime
```

(Note that you don't need to write out the `case` explicitly,
you can use the `maybe` function from the Prelude.)

Notice that I am also explicitly using `fromInteger` to push the
conversion through
the `Integer` type. If you want to go via `Int` instead (watch out for
the "Year 2038 Problem" on 32-bit machines), I would define a
separate conversion function to make that clear:

```
  return $ maybe ftime utcTimeToEpochTime etime
...

-- Convert from UTCTime to EpochTime via Int
utcTimeToEpochTime :: UTCTime -> EpochTime
utcTimeToEpochTime = fromIntegral . toSecs
  where
    toSecs :: UTCTime -> Int
    toSecs = round . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds
```

Comment: I'm copying pictures from a filesystem to another, using copyFile the file's date is lost, so I need to set it back to match the time the picture was taken.

Comment: @David V.: Yep, that'll do it. `System.Posix` it is.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `Data.Convertible.convert` (from the [convertible](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/convertible) package):

```hs
import Data.Convertible (convert)
import System.Posix.Types (EpochTime(..))
import Data.Time.Clock (UTCTime(..))

utcTimeToEpochTime :: UTCTime -> EpochTime
utcTimeToEpochTime = convert
```

Comment: Data.Convertible is neat.  If you run into a dependency problem with it: cabal install convertible --reinstall